# IE (all versions) following href instead of executing JS

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, href

I am having a problem with IE (who doesn't) in all versions of the browser. It works fine in every other browser.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>pages/delete_page/<?php echo $row->id; ?>" class="delete" data-uid="<?php echo $row->id; ?>">
    <i class="icon-cancel"></i><span class="delete_tooltip">delete page</span>
</a>
```

That is my `<a>` tag, and it is pretty simple.

Basically IE is following the href and not executing the JS at all. If I remove the link from the href, it just sends it back to the homepage.

I am using a plugin to load a modal box and like I said, everything works fine in every browser.

```
$('.delete').click(function(e) {    
  console.log($('#modal-'+$(this).data('uid')));    // Button which will activate our modal
  $('#modal-'+$(this).data('uid')).reveal({                // The item which will be opened with reveal
      animation: 'fadeAndPop',              // fade, fadeAndPop, none
      animationspeed: 400,            // how fast animtions are
      closeonbackgroundclick: false,   // if you click background will modal close?
      dismissmodalclass: 'modal_cancel'      // the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
  });
  return false;
});
```

And that is the JS that calls the plugin to that link.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a funny one...

`console.log($('#modal-'+$(this).data('uid')));` will cause an exception in IE so false is never returned causing the href to execute its default action.

Edit:
May have caused some confusion here. In IE it will cause an exception because `console` is `undefined`.

Comment: Oh excellent, thank you. I had no idea that IE did that. Learnt something today.

Comment: @chumkiu: `console` is only defined in IE if you have the Dev Tools open *before* your page is loaded.  It's flipping stupid.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.delete').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
```

Use `preventDefault()` inside your handler

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/ for reference

Comment: Thank you, this may come in handy in the future, but I had a console.log in my code...I didn't know that it made IE not work.